# Is there a way not to close the antd dropdown menu by clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

Im trying to implement an Antd Dropdown Menu with Search functionality, and wanted to close the dropdown when clicking outside. But in my code, along with clicking outside even if I click on the Search box, it toggles opening and closing of the dropdown(not desired). I want my dropdown menu to be open only if there is some character input in the search box and close if there is no character in the search box or if clicked outside, and it should not open and close if I go on just clicking on the search box itself. Is there any prop Im missing out on?
Here is the sample code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Menu, Dropdown, Input } from "antd";

class OverlayVisible extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible: false
  };

  handleMenuClick = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "3") {
      this.setState({ visible: false });
    }
  };

  handleVisibleChange = (flag) => {
    this.setState({ visible: flag });
  };

  render() {
    const menu = (
      <Menu onClick={this.handleMenuClick}>
        <Menu.Item key="1">Clicking me will not close the menu.</Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    );
    return (
      <Dropdown
        onClick={() => {
          this.setState({ visible: true });
        }}
        overlay={menu}
        onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}
        visible={this.state.visible}
        trigger={["click"]}
      >
        <Input.Search
          onInput={() => {
            this.setState({ visible: true });
          }}
        ></Input.Search>
        {/* <a className="ant-dropdown-link" onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
          Hover me <Icon type="down" />
        </a> */}
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<OverlayVisible />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

CodeSandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/aman-521r2?file=/index.js:0-1236

Comment: You could have use `Select` antd component for this.

Comment: In the `Select` antd component there is a `notFoundContent` API for specifying what to display if no search found. You could specify null to this API which will not show the dropdown if no data found.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the only option in this scenario

Comment: If you like my comment or answer then please accept my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Ran into the same issue and solved by adding `onClick={(e) => e?.stopPropagation()}` to the container where the click should not close the overlay

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31087191)

Comment: This answer solved my problem, and I will add the details below. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

**For AntDesign version 5+**

If you wish to prevent the dropdown from closing when a menu item is clicked, you can achieve this by creating a boolean state and handling two events. In the example below, I specify which menu item keys should close the dropdown and which ones should not. In this particular case, only the one with the key `menuItemKeyWhichShouldNotClose` does not close the dropdown, while the others do.

```
      <Dropdown
        open={open}
        menu={{
          items,
          onClick: (info: MenuInfo): void => {
            if (info.key !== menuItemKeyWhichShouldNotClose) setOpen(false)
          },
          onMouseLeave: (): void => setOpen(false),
        }}
      >
        <Button onMouseEnter={(): void => setOpen(true)}>
          <AiOutlineEllipsis />
        </Button>
      </Dropdown>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this by changing Input Search m

```
<Input.Search
          onChange={(e) => {
         
            if (e.target.value.length) {

              this.setState({ visible: true });
              return false;
            }
            this.setState({ visible: false });
          }}
        ></Input.Search>
```

and remove `setstate` from `handleVisibleChange`

```
  handleVisibleChange = (flag) => {
 
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your issue by passing `disabled` to the `Item` element like:

```
<Menu.Item key="1" disabled>Clicking me will not close the menu.</Menu.Item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add one more state for storing input values.

```
 state = {
    visible: false,
    value: ''
  };
```

Now set the value state when user type the value in the input

```
<Input.Search
   onInput={() => {
     this.setState({ visible: true });
   }}
   onChange={e => this.setState({value: e.target.value})}
   />
```

Now control the visibility of dropdown with the help of the length of the value.

```
  handleVisibleChange = (flag) => {
    if(this.state.value.length <= 0)
     this.setState({ visible: false });
    else
     this.setState({ visible: flag });
  };
```

Full code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Menu, Dropdown, Input } from "antd";

class OverlayVisible extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible: false,
    value: ''
  };

  handleMenuClick = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "3") {
      this.setState({ visible: false });
    }
  };

  handleVisibleChange = (flag) => {
    if(this.state.value.length<=0)
    this.setState({ visible: false });
    else
    this.setState({ visible: flag });
  };

  render() {
    const menu = (
      <Menu onClick={this.handleMenuClick}>
        <Menu.Item key="1">Clicking me will not close the menu.</Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    );
    return (
      <Dropdown
        onClick={() => {
          this.setState({ visible: true });
        }}
        overlay={menu}
        onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}
        visible={this.state.visible}
        trigger={["click"]}
      >
        <Input.Search
          onInput={() => {
            this.setState({ visible: true });
          }}
          onChange={e => this.setState({value: e.target.value})}
        ></Input.Search>
        {/* <a className="ant-dropdown-link" onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
          Hover me <Icon type="down" />
        </a> */}
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<OverlayVisible />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: That wouldn't work in the scenario where if I continuously click on the Search box, it toggles opening and closing of the Dropdown menu. That is something I want to avoid

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add my experience to [@raqibrasheed 786](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15012413/raqibrasheed-786)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71147325/9644424).
I faced the same problem to control the open status of dropdown menu. I was trying to build the multiselect with items with checkbox.

```js
type MultiSelectProps = {
  options: Array<{ value: string, label: string }>;
} & Partial<DropdownProps>;

export const MultiSelect: React.FC<MultiSelectProps> = ({
  options,
}) => {
  const handleOnClickOption = (e: any, val: string) => {
    // !!!this is the key point to stop propagation, so that the menu won't be closed on menu item click.
    e.stopPropagation();
    // describe your action on clicking each menu item.
  };

  const ignoreHandler = (e: any) => e.preventDefault();

  const menu = (<Menu
    items={options?.map(option => ({
      key: option.value,
      label:
        <div
          role="button"
          onClick={(e) => handleOnClickOption(e, option.value)}
        >
          {/* You component to render the menu item, but inogre all click event from the children */}
          <Checkbox
            checked={!!Math.floor(Math.random() + 1)}
            onClick={ignoreHandler}
          />
        </div>
    }))}
  />);

  return (
    <Dropdown
      className=""
      overlay={menu}
      trigger={["click"]}
    >
      {/* render soemthing for current status */}
    </Dropdown>
  );
};
```

The key points were

- to prevent the children items
- to stop propagation in the menu item wrapper.

So we can prevent the menu from closing a single click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the dropdown yourself through open state. example codes:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(true);
<Dropdown menu={{ items }} 
   open={open} 
   onOpenChange={(open) => {
     // control open by yourself
     // if you do not want to close dropdown, 
     // just do nothing, it will never close 
    }}>
    <a onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
      <Space>
        Cascading menu
        <DownOutlined />
      </Space>
    </a>
  </Dropdown>
```

also, check this sandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cascading-menu-antd-5-7-0-forked-vjmmvw?file=/demo.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this method:

- use custom `isOpen` and `setIsOpen`.
- wrapper with container with id such as `<div id={dropDownId} />`. and add `onClick` event.
- set prop `getPopupContainer` bind the container as above.

in this way, the `<Dropdown />` component is always in the container.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Button, Dropdown } from "antd";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const items = [
    {
      key: "1",
      label: "1",
      show: true,
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      label: "2",
      show: true,
    },
    {
      key: "3",
      label: "3",
      show: true,
    },
    {
      key: "4",
      label: "4",
      show: true,
    },
  ];

  const defaultSelectedKeys = items
    .filter((item) => item.show)
    .map((item) => item.key);

  const dropDownId = "drop-down-id";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id={dropDownId} onClick={() => setOpen(!isOpen)}>
        <Dropdown
          open={isOpen}
          menu={{
            getPopupContainer: () => 
 document.getElementById(dropDownId) as HTMLDivElement,
            selectable: true,
            multiple: true,
            onClick: ({ domEvent }) => {
              domEvent.stopPropagation();
            },
            items, // ...
            defaultSelectedKeys, // ...
          }}
        >
          <Button type="primary">show buttons</Button>
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is the sandbox example [demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/testttt-68zhfk)