# how to close the dropdown after selection antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

Goal:
Close the dropdown after selecting the option. This works on normal select dropdown but not while in tags.

Code:

```
 <Select
    mode="multiple"
    style={{ width: "100%" }}
    placeholder="select one country"
    defaultValue={["china"]}
    onChange={handleChange}
    optionLabelProp="label"
  >
    <Option value="china" label="China">
      <div className="demo-option-label-item">
        <span role="img" aria-label="China">
          
        </span>
        China (中国)
      </div>
    </Option>
    <Option value="usa" label="USA">
      <div className="demo-option-label-item">
        <span role="img" aria-label="USA">
          
        </span>
        USA (美国)
      </div>
    </Option>
    <Option value="japan" label="Japan">
      <div className="demo-option-label-item">
        <span role="img" aria-label="Japan">
          
        </span>
        Japan (日本)
      </div>
    </Option>
    <Option value="korea" label="Korea">
      <div className="demo-option-label-item">
        <span role="img" aria-label="Korea">
          
        </span>
        Korea (韩国)
      </div>
    </Option>
  </Select>
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-selection-render-antd-4-19-5-forked-9mm82d

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way not to close the antd dropdown menu by clicking on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67847206/is-there-a-way-not-to-close-the-antd-dropdown-menu-by-clicking-on-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useRef` on `Select` and call `blur` whenever a user triggers value changes on it

[The sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-selection-render-antd-4-19-5-forked-ymep31?file=/index.js)

```
import React, { useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const App = () => {
  //introduce `selectRef` for `Select`
  const selectRef = useRef()

  const handleChange = useCallback((value) => {
    selectRef.current.blur() //whenever a user triggers value change, we call `blur()` on `Select`
  }, [])

  return <Select
  mode="multiple"
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
  placeholder="select one country"
  defaultValue={["china"]}
  onChange={handleChange}
  optionLabelProp="label"
  ref={selectRef} //add ref here
>
  <Option value="china" label="China">
    <div className="demo-option-label-item">
      <span role="img" aria-label="China">
        
      </span>
      China (中国)
    </div>
  </Option>
  <Option value="usa" label="USA">
    <div className="demo-option-label-item">
      <span role="img" aria-label="USA">
        
      </span>
      USA (美国)
    </div>
  </Option>
  <Option value="japan" label="Japan">
    <div className="demo-option-label-item">
      <span role="img" aria-label="Japan">
        
      </span>
      Japan (日本)
    </div>
  </Option>
  <Option value="korea" label="Korea">
    <div className="demo-option-label-item">
      <span role="img" aria-label="Korea">
        
      </span>
      Korea (韩国)
    </div>
  </Option>
</Select>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

we dont need to use useRef. There is already predefined function are there

```
 const App = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Select
      defaultValue="lucy"
      style={{
        width: 300
      }}
      open={open}
      onDropdownVisibleChange={(visible) => setOpen(visible)}
      dropdownRender={(menu) => (
        <div>
          <div>
            top <Input />
          </div>
          {menu}
          <div>
            bottom{" "}
            <Button type="primary" onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
              click me to close
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    />
)}
```

[working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ji-ben-shi-yong-antd-4-21-7-forked-gnp4cy?file=/demo.js:167-733)

Comment: If you use "dropdownRender" this is the solution.